# Angular mat-form-field with FormControl and NgModel issue

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, form-control

I have a `mat-form-field` with an input box with `type="number"`.

I'm not sure if for my case I should use FormControl or NgModel.

I have a child component that `recieves` an Input object and I should save what's written in the input field onto a property of this object.

this is my child controller:

```
@Input()
  building: Building;  

@ViewChild("numberMatInput", {read: MatInput})
  numberMatInput: MatInput;
  numberInput: FormControl = new FormControl();

ngOnInit() {
    this.numberInput.valueChanges
    .subscribe(s => {
      this.building.radius = s;
    });
}
```

and my view is:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
     <mat-label>KM</mat-label>
     <input type="number" matInput #numberMatInput [formControl]="numberInput">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-icon matListIcon (click)="numberInput.setValue('')">close</mat-icon>
```

so it works, the input value gets saved onto the object property -> `this.building.radius` but what doesn't work, this is a panel that can be opened when selecting a building, and if I close the panel and open it again, the input field is empty instead of showing the latest value before closing the panel.

Should I use `NgModel`? so I can use on the `NgModel` directly `building.radius` ?

Sorry but I m pretty new to Angular!

Comment: If you are working on `Template driven forms` then `ngModel` or with `Reactive forms` then `FormControl`

Comment: Whats your angular version?

Comment: I m using angular 6.1.1

Answer (score 0):

for now I solved it like this, changed from FormControl to:

```
[(ngModel)]="building.radius"
```

and that's it, so it directly writes on the property of the object, not sure if it's the best way, but it works